# ArcGIS ModelBuilder Result Disappears?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

The resulting shapefile from my ArcGIS model is just disappearing after the model is finished running.

I see it for a short moment in catalogue but it doesn't show up in table of contents (I turned on add to display in the model).

Then if I refresh the folder that contains it in the catalogue, it also disappears from there.

Comment: When you turned on add to display is intermediate tick on? If so untick that.

Comment: That worked thanks. Now the shapefile is not getting deleted and is visible in the catalogue. But it still doesnt come up in table of contents even though add to displa is turned on in the model and also in geoprocessing options. Any ideas?

Comment: I have observed this problem before I think it is some sort of bug. I think if you set the tool's parameter as a _Model Parameter_ it will force it to add to TOC.

Comment: @Hornbydd I think you have enough in your comments to warrant a copy/paste into an answer.

Comment: I had to come back to this post because this time no matter what I do I cant find the output shapefile in the end. Its just being deleted I think. I have set the output to add to display and as model parameter and it is not intermediate data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have observed this problem before I think it is some sort of bug. I think if you set the tool's parameter as a Model Parameter it will force it to add to TOC - Hornbydd